# How to append arbitrary rows into a new data frame in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

I read in a Dataframe from a CSV file

`df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
 df`

```
Match   teamA  teamB
0       3      2
1       4      3
2       2      4
3       4      2
4       3      4
```

Now I want only row 0,1,3 because those are the rows that teamA won.
I want to know how I can take these rows and easily put them into a new DF. like

`newdf = df(row0,row1,row3)`

```
Match   teamA  teamB
0       3      2
1       4      3
3       4      2
```

EDIT: I need a solution that can work in all cases. Not just inequality arguments. I used this as a crude example but I need to grab specific arbitrary rows that otherwise have no relation to each other, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use boolean indexing to select the rows when teamA wins, i.e. teamA > teamB:

```
>>> df[df['teamA'].gt(df['teamB'])]  # `gt` = greater than
       teamA  teamB
Match              
0          3      2
1          4      3
3          4      2
```

To select arbitrary rows based on the row number (e.g. 0 and 2):

```
>>> df.iloc[[0, 2], :]
       teamA  teamB
Match              
0          3      2
2          2      4
```

Comment: What if I just want arbitrary rows?

Comment: `df[np.random.rand(len(df)) > .5]` will give you random rows with 50% probability.  What do you mean by 'arbitrary'?

Comment: How do I do it if I just want row 0 and 2? Thats what I mean by arbitrary.

Comment: `df.iloc[[0, 2], :]` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position